# Chart series point added not sync with X axis

Tags: c#, charts, highcharts, series

I try to draw Chart via C# with table as picture.
However, as you can see A4 data in date: 7 and 8/6 should stay with same 7 and 8/6 X-Axis, abnormal here all of them left to 5 & 6/6 X-Axis. Could you help me to fix it.

[image]

```
for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
        {
            string productname = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            string datetime = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            int para = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
            if (chart_dashboard.Series.IndexOf(productname) != -1)
            {
                chart_dashboard.Series[productname].Points.AddXY(datetime, para);
                chart_dashboard.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                chart_dashboard.Series.Add(productname);
                chart_dashboard.Series[productname].Points.AddXY(datetime, para);
                chart_dashboard.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A common mistake.

```
string datetime = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
```

This is wrong! If you add the x-values as strings they all are added as **`0`** and the `Series` can't align them to the proper slots on the X-Axis. So they get added from left to right sequentially..

Instead simply add the x-values as the `DateTimes` they are supposed to be!

So if the `Cells` contain `DateTime` values use:

```
DateTime datetime = (DateTime) dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;
```

If they don't, convert them to `DateTime`

```
DateTime datetime = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
```

To control the x-values type set the `XValueType` for each series:

```
chart_dashboard.Series[yourSeries].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
```

To control the way the axis labels are displayed set their formatting:

```
chart_dashboard[ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = someDateTimeFormatString;
```

---

To create a string like "Week 1" you would

- set the `XValueType` to `int16`
- add the x-value as the week numbers
- format it like `..axis.LabelStyle.Format = "Week #0";`

To extract the number from your data split by space and Convert.ToInt16 !

---

If one really needs to insert sparse x-values as strings one would have to insert a **dummy** `DataPoint` at each gap in a series.

Creating a dummy `DataPoint` is simple:

```
 DataPoint dp = new DataPoint() { IsEmpty = true};
```

But knowing where the gaps are **in advance** is the challenge! The 'best' way is to go over the data and filling in the before adding the points. Or go over it later and instead of **adding**,  **inserting** the dummys at the gaps. Both is a lot more trouble than getting the data right in the first place!

Comment: However, if DateTime value as string do we have any method to fix this problem.

Comment: I don't understand. Was that a question? Please explain! (If you meant what to do if you don't have a datetime or numeric value? Then you need to insert empty dummy points for each slot that is missing a point in a series; for this you still need to keep track of the x-values, which are lost unless you save them somehow. One spot would be the Tags of the DataPoints. But really providing good numeric/datetime data is the best way to go by far..)